# Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, centos

i've centos6.4 as server and centos7.5 as client. I am trying to connect perl client with oracle server. I downloaded DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz
and trying to install like this:-

Create file oci.conf at /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ as root with the location of  Oracle LD_LIBRARY_PATH

as

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2:
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
```

then

```
# ldconfig -v
```

this includes :-

```
ldconfig: Can't stat /libx32: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory

# perl Makefile.PL -V 11.2.0
```

this shows error :-

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/     
vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 10.
```

And there is no MakMaker in ExtUtils:

```
# perl -V:privlibexp
privlibexp='/usr/share/perl5'
```

Comment: What does `perl -V:privlibexp` give you? On my computer, `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` is installed in that directory

Comment: Iirc, centos is annoying and splits Perl up into multiple packages. Do you have `perl-core` installed?

Comment: You should probably install the DBI driver through your OS package manager too instead of trying to do it by hand. Or at least use a CPAN client

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*: `yum install perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker`.